# android - facebook premission ,Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

when I use [HelloFacebookSample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample) the code works fine and I was able to post on the user wall.

but when I try to post video and [embeded it on the wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202305/posting-an-embedded-youtube-link-using-the-facebook-sdk)  , to do so I used [publish to feed tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/)

when i convert my code i replace  `postStatusUpdate()` methood with `publishStory()`

```
public void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message ;



                message = ( user.getFirstName()+" "+ getString( R.string.status_update_link)+ " " +video_id + " " + getString(R.string.google_play_link));


            Request request = Request
                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }
```

replace with this :

```
private void publishStory() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null){

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {

                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();



                postParams.putString("message", getString( R.string.google_play_link));
                postParams.putString("link", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+ video_id);
                postParams.putString("source", "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + video_id);
                postParams.putString("picture","http://img.youtube.com/vi/" +video_id + "/0.jpg");





    Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                       .getGraphObject()
                                       .getInnerJSONObject();
            String postId = null;
            try {
                postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i(TAG,
                    "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
            }
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {


                Toast.makeText(MyApp.intense,
                     error.getErrorMessage(),
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                /** 
                    Toast.makeText(MyApp.intense, 
                        // postId
                            "Sent"
                         ,
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 */        
            }
        }
    };

    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                          HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}

}
```

so when i try to post, the app is cresh and I recieve " Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request"

I dont find when the first permission...

in other Q that posted in this form the developer recieve the same error MSG like I receive but it look like this error appear when the [session is not  OPENED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932885/session-an-attempt-was-made-to-request-new-permissions-for-a-session-that-has-a) and the user call it, I belive that not the problem in this case.

I attached more code from this FragmentActivity because I believe it necessary.

```
 private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE &&
                (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                    .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
                postStatusUpdateButton.setEnabled(false);
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
            handlePendingAction();
        }
        updateUI();
    }




private enum PendingAction {
        NONE,

        POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I delete all the code and restart from the begining , and the problem solved..

Answer (score 1):

You can just add  `pendingPublishReauthorization = true;`

```
//so
if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
     pendingPublishReauthorization = true;

            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }
```

It's working for me.

Hope this help

Comment: thank you for your quick answer but I try this and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);` will generate a Facebook dialog asking the user to give the permission.  You need to `@Override onActivityResult()` to capture and apply what comes back form the Facebook dialog.  In my app I first ask the user to authenticate my app, and then ask for permission to access their Groups...

```
public class FacebookManage extends Activity {
    // Facebook
    private Session         fbSession       = null;
    private int             authCount       = 0;

    // There is a UI button that calls addAccount();

    public void addAccount(View v) {
        // Open a new Session
        OpenRequest or = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
        or.setCallback(null);
        // Login
        Session.Builder sb = new Session.Builder(this);
        Session session = sb.build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        // This will bring up a Facebook dialog and return a call to onActivityResult
        session.openForRead(or);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == Session.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            if (authCount == 0) {
                // This is the first authentication where we got basic access to the user account
                Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
                fbSession = Session.getActiveSession();
                if (fbSession != null && !fbSession.isClosed()) {
                    // Ask for Group permission
                    authCount++;
                    List<String> fbPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
                    fbPermissions.add("user_groups");
                    NewPermissionsRequest snpr = new NewPermissionsRequest(this, fbPermissions);
                    fbSession.requestNewReadPermissions(snpr);
                }
            } else if (authCount == 1) {
                // Returning from asking for access to "Groups"
                if (fbSession != null && !fbSession.isClosed()) {
                    // This will add the group permission to the current session
                    fbSession.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I actually do three rounds of asking for permissions (Initial, Groups, Pages and Publish) and just use the `authCount` to keep track of where I am.  The user sees 4 Facebook dialogs, but the nice thing they have but single "permission" requests each.  You get the idea...

I just call `fbSession.close();` when I'm all done.  Then the access token is cached and managed by the Facebook SDK.  By using one Activity to do the Authentication and letting the SDK keep track of that, in other activities (pages) I just need to call `fbSession = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this);` and I'm good to go.

(Note - if the user goes into their Facebook settings and specifically nukes some of the permissions you originally asked for, you won't know it until you try and publish.  Ah, error trapping...)